# Prolog practice, need to figure out why Im getting errors

Tags: prolog

Hey I am studying for an exam and I cant figure out one of the practice questions. Can I get some help please.

This is the question: Define a predicate called power10 which takes two parameters. power10(X,P) should be true if
and only if P is the number of times X may be divided evenly by 10. In other words, you're figuring
out how many zeros there are at the end of X. (But if you know how to convert an integer to a string in
Prolog you may not use that to find your answer!) You may assume that X is bound to a positive
integer. P may be bound or unbound.

This is what I have so far, Im getting errors and im not sure how to get it to output my P value.

```
power10(X,P):-
    X mod 10 =\= 0.

power10(X,P):-
    X mod 10 =:= 0,
    Remainder is X//10,
    power10(Remainder,Counter),
    P is Counter+1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first predicate, you are never assigning a value to `P`. Try this:

```
power10(X, 0) :-
    X mod 10 =\= 0.
```

Comment: LOL, thanks a lot. It's always little mistakes like this that get me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2303093 No problem. :) If this answered your question, would you mind accepting it by clicking the check mark next to the answer?

Comment: ahh there you go, sorry this is my first time using this site. Definitely wont be the last though.